# When using an .htaccess file I get an internal error, but why?

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am trying to use a custom .htaccess file but everytime I put it inside my root directory I get the following error:

> Internal Server Error
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

This is how my file looks like:
`ErrorDocument 404 /e404.html`

And this is my e404.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">  
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
        <title>Error 404</title>
    </head>
    <body></body>   
</html>
```

[Here is my file](https://download1498.mediafire.com/dbrsouioqpyg/izkug4wrl8hzvxl/.htaccess)

Comment: Do you still see the error if you remove the `ErrorDocument` directive?

Comment: e404.html ? you say 404.html in htaccess

Comment: You checked your apache error logs?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a spelling mistake, my bad. Than I remove the ErrorDoucment line, everything works fine.

Comment: Please check your error log file for information about the 500 error.

Comment: "Internal Server Error" isn't the actual error, it's just a generic message that warns you some "something" failed. The real error message will be in the log files: please look for it. For some reason many people are reluctant to do so, but it's pointless to try to guess when you can just read it.

Comment: Most likely you have a syntax error in your distributed configuration file (".htaccess"). The http server's error log file will tell you what the exact issue is. You cannot develop and maintain a web presence without monitoring that file.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, please do check the permission you have set up for the custom `.htaccess` file. This is because chances are that Apache is unable to access that `.htaccess file`, since you're the user who created it and you're the only one who has the permissions for accessing and reading that file.

It's also possible that there has been issues with the service you're trying to connect to, by that I mean:

- PHP timeout: The script tries to access an external resource and experiences a timeout.
- Incorrect code in .htaccess: The structure in a .htaccess file could be wrong.
- Error in syntax or code in CGI/Perl scripts: In some cases, scripts are incorrect. Paths, especially, can be misaligned.
- PHP memory limit: A process exceeds memory and therefore cannot be executed correctly.

Comment: good point. hat this problem once as well

Comment: Im not quite sure where I can see who can edit the file. Im using UnraidOS and installed the Apache container. I just uploaded the website files via ftp and thats it.

Comment: Do mark as answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Obscuritas right-click on the file and then click on properties to view the permissions set for that file

Comment: @Ridwan its not write protected or something like that

Comment: OP is getting a 500 server error when he inserts the `ErrorDocument` so obviously the server is reading their htaccess file.

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess file then? I suppose there's something wrong in that configuration of the .htaccess file

Comment: I linked the file in the post. I dont think its a php or perl problem. Never used them

Comment: Can you directly paste it here?

Comment: By the way, does your site work without the .htaccess file?

Comment: Can you tell me how I post it here, I dont find an option for that. The website works without the file and even then Im putting it in the directory it only shows the error, when Im trying to access a non existent site.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not really an answer to the actual question. It is just a collection of general hints, none of them clearly connected to the specific issue. A file permission issue for example would _not_ lead to the described issue.